# Imitate 2000s era renders in 3.3+

Tags: rendering, shaders, versions, keymap

Is there any way to recreate these kinds of renders?

I have been able to only replicate the old Perlin noise with texture paint, sadly. Utilizing the layer weight node for some of the materials.

The real issue is the unavailability of Blender's old RRV internal render engine which is eighty percent of the look I am trying to replicate.

I have included some examples of what I am trying to get at.

[image: Render by Scott Cawthon]

[image: From the defunct Internet Raytracing Competition]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is a highly subjective topic, but some things you could do to replicate this are as follows:

1. Use really low-res textures
2. Keep models low-poly
3. Take down a ton of the light bounces for Cycles so it doesn't render that realistic images
4. Stay away from using complex materials
5. Don't use HDRIs...use a world color instead.
6. Use point lights and area/spot lights instead of sun lights